# Two equivalent definitions of continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, definition

In the book Topology: A Geometric Approach, two equivalent definitions of continuity. The first one is pretty basic. It is this:
**Definition $1.1.1$**. $f$ is continuous at $x \in X$ if, given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ so
that $d(x, y) < δ$ implies that $d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$. Here $d$ is the Euclidean distance function:
$$d((x_1,...x_n),(y_1,...y_n))=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-y_i)^2}$$
Also, second definition is given:
**Definition $1.1.2$.** $f : X → Y$ is continuous at $x ∈ X$ if given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $δ > 0$ so that $B_X(\mathbf{x},\delta)\subset f^{-1}(B_Y(f(x),\epsilon))$.
Where a *ball of radius $r$ about $z$*, denoted by $B(z,r)$, is defined as $\{y\in\Bbb{R}:d(y,x)<r\}$, and $B_C(z,r)$, where $C$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}^k$, is defined to be $C\cap B(z,r)$. Next, they give the problem to show that the two definitions are equivalent. How can we do that? I am a beginner in topology, and I am sometimes bad in noticing in obvious things. And also the language and notation makes it look like that there's nothing obvious (even if there is something obvious) so please tell in the comments if I didn't notice something that was obvious.

Comment: If you carefully write out what $B_X(x, \delta) \subset f^{-1}(B_Y(f(x), \epsilon))$ means, everything will just be self-evident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$d(x,y)<\delta\iff y\in B_X(x,\delta)$$and that\begin{align}d\bigl(f(x),f(y)\bigr)<\varepsilon&\iff f(y)\in B_Y\bigl(f(x),\varepsilon\bigr)\\&\iff y\in f^{-1}\left(B_Y\bigl(f(x),\varepsilon\bigr)\right).\end{align}Can you take it from here?